# STORAGE Permissions after Android 13

Tags: android, react-native

i need to help zoom meeting app after update sdk (5.14.2.13167) Permissions problem,

Working fine with android 6 to 12 only permissions problem with android 13

```
compileSdkVersion 33
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** and **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permissions from your manifest.

Update your code to use the storage access framework or Media Store API to access media files. This involves using the **ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT** intent to let users select files and the **DocumentFile** **API** to perform read and write operations on those files. Here's an example of how you can use the storage access framework:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

And in your onActivityResult method:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    // Use the uri to read/write the selected file
    // ...
}
```

If you want to more info: [Go to](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider)

Comment: Md. Kabir Hassan - Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since most or all seven of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.